# Application forcefully closes

Tags: android, android-activity

I've created tab view and now I am trying to swich to again tab after completion of task using intent, but the application forcefully closed. My error log is as below:

```
06-09 12:48:35.261: WARN/dalvikvm(439): threadid=3: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001aa28)
06-09 12:48:35.261: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(439): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
06-09 12:48:35.273: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(439): java.lang.NullPointerException
06-09 12:48:35.273: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(439):     at com.androidpeople.tab.MobiintheMorningActivity$HelloWebViewClient.onPageFinished(MobiintheMorningActivity.java:107)
06-09 12:48:35.273: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(439):     at android.webkit.CallbackProxy.handleMessage(CallbackProxy.java:222)
06-09 12:48:35.273: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(439):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-09 12:48:35.273: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(439):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
06-09 12:48:35.273: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(439):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4203)
06-09 12:48:35.273: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(439):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-09 12:48:35.273: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(439):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
06-09 12:48:35.273: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(439):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:791)
06-09 12:48:35.273: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(439):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:549)
06-09 12:48:35.273: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(439):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-09 12:48:35.293: INFO/Process(52): Sending signal. PID: 439 SIG: 3
06-09 12:48:35.293: INFO/dalvikvm(439): threadid=7: reacting to signal 3
06-09 12:48:35.332: INFO/dalvikvm(439): Wrote stack trace to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
06-09 12:48:35.502: INFO/System.out(439): #: 2
06-09 12:48:35.502: WARN/dalvikvm(439): threadid=31: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001aa28)
06-09 12:48:35.523: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(439): Uncaught handler: thread  exiting due to uncaught exception
06-09 12:48:35.523: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(439): java.lang.NullPointerException
06-09 12:48:35.523: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(439):     at com.androidpeople.tab.MobiintheMorningActivity$t2.run(MobiintheMorningActivity.java:218)
06-09 12:48:35.523: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(439):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1060)
06-09 12:48:35.543: INFO/Process(52): Sending signal. PID: 439 SIG: 3
06-09 12:48:35.543: WARN/ActivityManager(52): Process com.androidpeople.tab has crashed too many times: killing!
06-09 12:48:35.552: INFO/dalvikvm(439): threadid=7: reacting to signal 3
06-09 12:48:35.552: INFO/dalvikvm(439): Wrote stack trace to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
06-09 12:48:35.602: INFO/Process(52): Sending signal. PID: 439 SIG: 9
06-09 12:48:35.683: INFO/WindowManager(52): WIN DEATH: Window{4394ce88 com.androidpeople.tab/com.androidpeople.tab.CopyOfTabBarExample paused=true}
06-09 12:48:45.592: WARN/ActivityManager(52): Launch timeout has expired, giving up wake lock!
```

When I am trying find error from log it shows me this line.

My full code:

```
package com.androidpeople.tab;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class activityname extends Activity {
    /**
     *================== VARIABLE AND CONTROL DECLARATION========
     */
    public static final int DIALOG_DOWNLOAD_PROGRESS = 0;
    ProgressBar myProgressBar;
    int myProgress = 0;
    private static final String LOG_TAG = "Test";
    final Context myApp = this;
    private WebView mWebView;
    Button btn, btn1;
    /**
     * ==================== URL =================================
     */
    private static final String strURL = "http://www.myURL";
    /**
     * ========================================================================
     * ==
     */
    final Activity activity = this;

    /**
     *========END OF VARIABLE AND CONTROL DECLARATION==============
     */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.mainforload);
        Button btn=(Button) findViewById(R.id.My_btn);
        mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webviewHelp);
        mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        mWebView.addJavascriptInterface(new MyjavascriptInterface(), "HTMLOUT");
        mWebView.loadUrl(strURL);
        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new HelloWebViewClient());
    }
    /**
     * 
     * =================THIS IS USED FOR GETTING SOURCE CODE===================
     * 
     */
    public class MyjavascriptInterface {
        public void showHTML(String html) {
            try {
                String struniqID = "<div id=\"uniqueid\">";
                mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webviewHelp);    

                if (html.toString().contains(struniqID)) {
                    GlobalVariable.SetTemp(1);                  
                    String temp[] = html.toString().split(struniqID);
                    String strDiv = "</div>";                   
                    String temp1[] = temp[1].split(strDiv);
                    String strUidPswd = "&username=test&password=test";                 
                    String s = temp1[0].concat(strUidPswd);             
                    GlobalVariable.Setstr(s.toString());

                    try {
                        new Thread(new t(), "" + "").start();
                        // new temp().start();
                    } catch (Exception e) {

                    }
                } else {
                    GlobalVariable.SetTemp(0);
                    new Thread(new t2(), "" + "").start();

                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.i(LOG_TAG, e.toString() + "");
                Toast.makeText(myApp, e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    }

    public class HelloWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            view
                    .loadUrl("javascript:window.HTMLOUT.showHTML('<head>'+document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML+'</head>');");
            if (GlobalVariable.GetTemp() == 1) {
                final Button btn=(Button) findViewById(R.id.My_btn);
                btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View arg0) {
                        try {
                            btn.requestFocus();

                            Intent i = new Intent(
                                    activityname.this,
                                    anotheractivityname.class);
                            finish();
                            startActivity(i);
//                          finish();

                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            Log.i(LOG_TAG, e.toString());
                        }
                    }
                });
            } else {
                btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.My_btn);
                btn.requestFocus();
                btn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }

            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideKeyEvent(WebView view, KeyEvent event) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (GlobalVariable.GetTemp() == 1) {

            }
            return super.shouldOverrideKeyEvent(view, event);
        }

    }

    /**
     * ==============================THIS CLASS FOR DISPLAYING
     * BUTTON============================
     */
    class t implements Runnable {
        private int countDown = 2;

        public String toString() {
            return "#" + Thread.currentThread().getName() + ": " + countDown;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            while (true) {
                System.out.println(this);

                btn.post(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {

                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        if (GlobalVariable.GetTemp() == 1) {
                            btn.requestFocus();
                            btn.setVisibility(0);
                            // int i=0;
                            btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                                @Override
                                public void onClick(View arg0) {
try{
                                    Intent i = new Intent(
                                            activityname.this,
                                            anotheractivity.class);
                                     finish();
                                    startActivity(i);

//                                   finish();
                                    }catch (Exception e) {
                                        // TODO: handle exception
                                    }
                                    // quit();
                                }
                            });
                        }
                        if (GlobalVariable.GetTemp() == 0) {
                            btn.requestFocus();
                            btn.setVisibility(4);
                        }
                    }
                });
                if (--countDown == 1)
                    return;
            }
        }
    }

    // =================================
    class t2 implements Runnable {
        private int countDown = 2;

        public String toString() {
            return "#" + Thread.currentThread().getName() + ": " + countDown;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            while (true) {
                System.out.println(this);
                btn.post(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        if (GlobalVariable.GetTemp() == 0) {
                            try{
                            btn.requestFocus();
                            btn.setVisibility(4);}catch (Exception e) {
                                // TODO: handle exception
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
                if (--countDown == 1)
                    return;
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * =========== THIS CUSTOM METHOD IS FOR CLOSING THE CURRENT EXECUTING
     * PROCESS===================
     */
    public void quit() {
        int pid = android.os.Process.myPid();
        android.os.Process.killProcess(pid);
        System.exit(0);

    }
}
```

and this is my tabbar file that  extends TabActivity

```
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.maiin);
        final TabHost tabHost = (TabHost) getTabHost();
        try {
            tabHost.addTab(createTab(activityname.class, "Welcome",
                    "Welcome", R.drawable.tab_icon_events));
            tabHost.addTab(createTab(anotheractivityname.class, ".Mp3List", ".Mp3List",
                    R.drawable.tab_icon_pitchforkfm));
            tabHost.addTab(createTab(AboutUs.class, "AboutUs", "AboutUs",
                    R.drawable.tab_icon_home));
            tabHost.addTab(createTab(ExitActivity.class, "EXIT", "EXIT",
                    R.drawable.tab_icon_tv));

            tabHost.setCurrentTab(1);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
        }
        tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(0).getLayoutParams().width = 85;
        tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(1).getLayoutParams().width = 85;
        tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(2).getLayoutParams().width = 85;
        tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(3).getLayoutParams().width = 85;

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
            moveTaskToBack(false);

            return true;
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }

    private TabSpec createTab(final Class<?> intentClass, final String tag,
            final String title, final int drawable) 
    {
        final Intent intent = new Intent().setClass(this, intentClass);

        final View tab = LayoutInflater.from(getTabHost().getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.tab, null);
        ((TextView) tab.findViewById(R.id.tab_text)).setText(title);
        ((ImageView) tab.findViewById(R.id.tab_icon))
                .setImageResource(drawable);

        return getTabHost().newTabSpec(tag).setIndicator(tab)
                .setContent(intent);

    }
}
```

Comment: Well, seems like `btn` is null, you don't show us where you declared / initialized it, so it's hard to tell more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to initialize the button in inside activity class , otherwise it won`t work , then use that button in WebViewClient class.

Answer (score 1):

You're getting a NullPointerException...that means something is pointing to a null in your code.From what I see, maybe its your button btn??? Inside the if clause, btn doesn't seem to have been initialized.Try adding the following line inside the if block before setting a listener on it.

```
btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.My_btn);
```